# VichUploader : MediaObject is not uploadable

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, vichuploaderbundle

I try to upload file throught a REST API with API Plateform

I followed the doc, but I got :

```
"The class \"App\\Entity\\MediaObject\" is not uploadable. If you use attributes to configure VichUploaderBundle, you probably just forgot to add `#[Vich\\Uploadable]` on top of your entity. If you don't use attributes, check that the configuration files are in the right place. In both cases, clearing the cache can also solve the issue.",
```

I'am using :

```
"api-platform/core": "^3.0",
"vich/uploader-bundle": "^2.0"
```

My config :

```
# api/config/packages/vich_uploader.yaml
vich_uploader:
  db_driver: orm
  metadata:
    type: attribute
  mappings:
    media_object:
      uri_prefix: /media
      upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/media'
      namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\OrignameNamer
```

My entity :

```
<?php
// api/src/Entity/MediaObject.php
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use App\Controller\CreateMediaObjectAction;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

#[Vich\Uploadable]
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['media_object:read']], 
    types: ['https://schema.org/MediaObject'],
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new GetCollection(),
        new Post(
            controller: CreateMediaObjectAction::class, 
            deserialize: false, 
            validationContext: ['groups' => ['Default', 'media_object_create']], 
            openapiContext: [
                'requestBody' => [
                    'content' => [
                        'multipart/form-data' => [
                            'schema' => [
                                'type' => 'object', 
                                'properties' => [
                                    'file' => [
                                        'type' => 'string', 
                                        'format' => 'binary'
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        )
    ]
)]
class MediaObject
{
    #[ORM\Id, ORM\Column, ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ApiProperty(types: ['https://schema.org/contentUrl'])]
    #[Groups(['media_object:read'])]
    public ?string $contentUrl = null;

    #[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: "media_object", fileNameProperty: "filePath")]
    #[Assert\NotNull(groups: ['media_object_create'])]
    public ?File $file = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)] 
    public ?string $filePath = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird, i dont see anything wrong. I compared it to my own class which use Vich and we got the same configuration.
Did you try a "composer dump-autoload" just to refresh classes or whatever that clear the cache ?

Comment: yes I did this and cache:clear, restart all, but it's not working =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this resolved the problem:

```
composer require doctrine/annotations
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).